# $f(z) = z^k + kz$ is injective in the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I go around proving that $f(z) = z^k + kz$ in injective in the open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$, for each natural $k$?

I don't really know where to start. I observed that its derivative is nonzero, but that was all that I came up with.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: More generally, [if $\mathrm{Re}\,f'>0$ on a convex domain, then $f$ is injective](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/300536/). And you have $f'(z)=k(z^{k-1}+1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $z_1^k+kz_1=z_2^k+kz_2$ then

$$(z_1-z_2)\left( z_1^{k-1}+z_1^{k-2}z_2+...+z_2^{k-1}+k\right)=0$$

**Hint** if $z_1,z_2$ are in the open unit disk, then by the triangle inequality

$$\left| z_1^{k-1}+z_1^{k-2}z_2+...+z_2^{k-1} \right| < k \,.$$